# IDE PyCharm sobre Windows

Tags: python-3.x, ide, pycharm

Já tenho costume de utilizar o PyCharm sobre o GNU/Linux, e por força maior terei que usá-lo sobre o Windows.

**O problema é o seguinte:** Ao executar o programa python pelo IDE, um crawler python, o programa não finaliza. É como se entrasse em loop infinito. E devido a isto o html não é gravado em disco.

**Pergunta:** Como finaliza a excução de um script python no console da IDE PyCharm rodando em MS/Windows?

**Observação:** O código executado foi gerado no Linux. E funciona perfeitamente.

**Trecho de Exemplo:**

```
import requests
import inspect
def truncus05d(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    with open('{}.html'.format(inspect.stack()[0][3]), 'w') as file:
        file.write(page.text.strip())
```

Código completo em:  https://pastebin.com/qdCNHueT

Comment: E qual é o código? Poste-o na pergunta.

Comment: segue o código: https://pastebin.com/UW73pdDH

Comment: Coloca na pergunta ou faz um [mcve]